# Xamarin forms inside Constructor display alert not showing?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to display alert in my main page loading time. So i declared display alert in my constructor. But i didn't get any response.

I have attached my sample code.

```
public Home()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    if (!(Plugin.Connectivity.CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected))
    {

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path + "App" + "/Data.txt"))
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Success", "Saved", "OK");
            });

        }
        else
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Oops", "Login Required", "OK");
            });

        }

    }
    else
    {
        GetDetails();
    }

}
```

Comment: Is your code going in the first if block?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `constructor` is meant to keep `Initialization` code. The`OnAppearing()` method is called when the `Page` is about to be displayed.The `displayAlert()` will succeed inside this method. This is the sample code.

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {

        Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Success", "Saved", "OK");

        base.OnAppearing();

}
```

Keep you initialization code in the `constructor` or `new Task(Init).Start();` as suggested in other answer. Save the status of `if` `else` in field of type `bool`. Alter the message in the `OnAppearing()` method according to the field.

Answer (score 1):

You can not directly `await` a `Task` within the .ctor of a class (search SO there are plenty of Q&A on this).

In your .ctor, after the `InitializeComponent` start a void Task (fire and forget style):

```
new Task(Init).Start();
```

The void task `Init` will look like:

```
async void Init()
{
    if (!(Plugin.Connectivity.CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected))
    {
        ~~~
    }
    else
    {
        GetDetails();
    }
}
```

Comment: The suggestion to start new Task in the constructor is wonderful. But it still don't show the message because the page is not loaded. The page will load after the initialization code is executed.

Comment: @Sushi Thanks for your answer. But its not working for me. First answer is working ..

Comment: Same here guys, Application.Current.MainPage... seemed to be what I was missing in the OnAppearing() routine.  Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

in `InitializeComponent()` you have used like
 `await DisplayAlert("Success", "Saved", "OK");`
instead of this use like  `Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Success", "Saved", "OK");`
then it will work fine.